# vb6 form auto reloads

Tags: forms, events, vb6

I'm working on a VB6 app that was coded by someone else a long time ago. When it's doing its thing, the form reloads on exit in an attempt to retry(?).

Does anyone know how this would be accomplished so that I can STOP IT.  I've dug through the entire program and can't see where this would be happening.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely the form or one of its controls is being referenced ***after*** it has been unloaded, and this is causing it to re-load.

The easiest way to tell what is causing it is to run the form, put a [BreakPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231226%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) at the end of the `Form_Load` event then close it. Then, when it re-loads, press F8 to (hopefully*) step into the line of code immediately following the one that caused it.

Once you have established what the cause is, it ought to be relatively straightforward to amend your code to prevent it.

**Timer events or other asynchronous code may divert execution away from the culprit code, in which case you will have to first stop any affecting processes – timers etc. – in the immediate window before you begin to step forward with F8.*